# В чем разница этих событий?

Tags: unity3d

На практике не вижу разницы в двух событиях. Возможно в них есть скрытая разница ?

```
private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        { 
            print("Down0");
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
        {
            print("Down0"); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetMouseButtonDown` - позволяет отслеживать только кнопки мыши (название даже намекает), а `GetKeyDown` ввод с клавиатуры и контроллеров. Так же
[InputManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html) позволяет вам давать свои строковые имена различным кнопками и их сочетаниям и использовать их в `GetButtonDown`.

Comment: Следовательно можно использовать GetKeyDown для всех устройств. А GetMouseButtonDown работает локально по событиям для мыши ?

Comment: @KDN77RUS Можно и так сказать, вместо `GetMouse` на мобильных устройствах используются тачи